# Autoit Error with iframe

Tags: autoit

```
$aArray = _IEFrameGetCollection($ObjIE)
$max = @extended
ConsoleWrite("Array Length: " & $max & @CR)
For $item in $aArray
    ConsoleWrite("Value" & $item.src)
Next
```

The code causes the following error:

--> COM Error Encountered in ITSM-GUI-Automation.au3 
----> $IEComErrorScriptline = 106
----> $IEComErrorNumberHex = 80020003
----> $IEComErrorNumber = -2147352573
----> $IEComErrorWinDescription = Member not found.
----> $IEComErrorDescription = 
----> $IEComErrorSource = 
----> $IEComErrorHelpFile = 
----> $IEComErrorHelpContext = 0
----> $IEComErrorLastDllError = 0

The weird thing is that $max is getting set to 3 but then it cannot find the iframes. How can it find it and immediately not find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of my lack of understanding of the Autoit objects. This does not return an array of objects but a collection which must be accessed through a different way.

Hope this helps someone else.

```
$collection = _IEFrameGetCollection($ObjIE)
$max = @extended
ConsoleWrite("Array Length: " & $max & @CR)
For $item = 0 to $max - 1
    $obj = IEFrameGetCollection($ObjIE, $item)
    ConsoleWrite("Value" & $item.src)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <IE.au3>

Local $oIE = _IE_Example("frameset")
Local $oFrames = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE)
Local $iNumFrames = @extended
For $i = 0 To ($iNumFrames - 1)
    Local $oFrame = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE, $i)
    $FrameHTML = _IEDocReadHTML($oFrame); or
    $FrameHTML = _IEPropertyGet($oFrame, "innerhtml"); or
    $FrameHTML = _IEPropertyGet($oFrame, "outerhtml")
    ConsoleWrite($FrameHTML & @LF)
Next
```